# Viewing Location on google map sending Latitude and Longitude

Tags: android

I want to view the location on google `map` my app get the latitude and longitude of the location but the location does not show in google map. I used firebase database to store **latitude** and **longitude**

**here is the code of map activity**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    mMap = map;
    // TODO: Before enabling the My Location layer, you must request
    // location permission from the user. This sample does not include
    // a request for location permission.
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMyLocationClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onMyLocationClick(@NonNull Location location) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Current location:\n" + location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyLocation button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Return false so that we don't consume the event and the default behavior still occurs
    // (the camera animates to the user's current position).
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate when do you need to get the location. Do you need to show location stored in Firebase database? Or do you need to show location on clicking at any point in the map?

Comment: need to show location stored in Firebase database

Answer (score 0):

Use this method and pass 4 parameter to this given method. First it will navigation to a particular place also add marker of that place.

Example:

```
public static Marker addPinPoint(GoogleMap map, Marker locationMarker, double selectLatitude, double selectLongitude){
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(locationLatitude, locationLongitude), fZoom));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    Bitmap iconImage = ResourceUtil.getBitmap(App.getInstance().getContext(), R.drawable.icon_location_center); // your location icon
    BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconImage);
    locationMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f)
            .icon(icon)
            .position(new LatLng(selectLatitude, selectLongitude)));
    return locationMarker;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to show marker on a specific latitude and longitude, on your `onMapReady` function:

```
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)); 
mMap.addMarker(marker);
```

The `latitude` and `longitude` should be the one you fetch from Firebase.